# How to get the same object from another process?

Tags: c#, dll, exe

Is it possible to use the same object in two process?

Here are the steps in my case:
First, when I open the particular application, the DLL file will create a class and get the object that from the application.
Next, I open an EXE file.
The EXE file will use this object and do some procedure.

When I open the particular application, it will create a form application automatically.
Here is my code in DLL file:

First:

```
public class myClassSample
{
    public object module
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Second:

```
Form newForm;
static BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance;

myClassSample classSample = new myClassSample();
classSample.module = module;
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("mySample.exe");
Type formType = assembly.GetType("mySample.Form1");
Form resultForm = assembly.CreateInstance(formType.FullName) as Form;
newForm = resultForm;
Type type = newForm.GetType();
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty("serverModule", flags);
propertyInfo.SetValue(newForm, module);
newForm.Show();
```

It seems to be ok, but I have to open a certain application first.
I wish I could open the EXE file individually.

Like, when I open the EXE file, the object is null.
The object will get after the specific application is opening.

Comment: If you mean the same instance of a class, then you will have to use some form of inter-process communication to access the information of the instance in one process from the other process. If you mean the same class: yes sure, just reference the DLL from both programs.

Comment: Klaus:
I mean the same instance of a class. I tried IPC program to achieve my goal. But It can't get the object in another form.
I code two console app and a dll file. The dll file is the class. In one console app that created a new class and setted the string, But it couldn't show the string in another console app.

Comment: This will not work, as two running applications have distinct memory areas for their data. You really need to set up some communication channel between the apps.

Comment: To add to what Klaus is saying, a simple way of doing this would be to serialize to file from one app and deserialize from the other app. This 'just works' and has several limitations.

Comment: I just visted this website : https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/local-machine-interprocess-communication-with-net
I think this is what you mention.